# Trouble with syntax accessing multidimentional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a difficult time getting the syntax correct when trying to access the values in this array. Here is the array and after I will show you what I have tried.

```
[_POST] => Array
(
    [type] => subscribe
    [fired_at] => 2014-03-11 16:15:11
    [data] => Array
        (
            [id] => a23a8866cd
            [email] => mccoym@sportdirections.com
            [email_type] => html
            [ip_opt] => 65.96.140.144
            [ip_signup] => 65.96.140.144
            [web_id] => 145475077
            [merges] => Array
                (
                    [EMAIL] => mccoym@sportdirections.com
                    [FNAME] => Michael
                    [LNAME] => McCoy
                    [MMERGE3] => 10/17
                )

            [list_id] => e375c4fd87
        )

)
```

I am trying to get the information stored in the merges array. I have tried:

```
$_POST['data']->merges['EMAIL']
$_POST['data']->merges->EMAIL
$_POST['data']['merges']->EMAIL
```

none of the above work! can anyone help me get the syntax correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$_POST['data']['merges']['EMAIL']
```

Comment: @McCoy This code should work fine.  Your output above though doesn't seem to be `print_r($_POST)`, but something else.  Since you don't show what you're actually doing, all we can do is guess,. and Mundshark's answer is the best answer there can be with the information given.